# backbone supermodel.js -- lost associations of models after fetching from localStorage

Tags: backbone.js, model, relationship

I have two Backbone SuperModel `Info` and `Content`, and associate `1-to-1` with each other in the way:

```
 Info.has().one('content', {
      model: Content,
      inverse: 'info'
 });

 Content.has().one('info', {
      model: Info,
      inverse: 'content'
 });
```

and saved instances of these two Models into different localStorages:

```
Info.all().localStorage = new Backbone.LocalStorage('info'); // all() returns the collection.
Content.all().localStorage = new Backbone.LocalStorage("content"); 

// instances of Info Model. 'id' would be generated when calling initialize()
var info1 = Info.create();
var info2 = Info.create();

var content1 = Content.create({
    info_id: info1.get('id')
});
var content2 = Content.create({
    info_id: info2.get('id')
});

// save to localStorage
info1.save();
info2.save();

content1.save();
content2.save();
```

While after fetched them out, all of the associations get lost:

```
Info.all().fetch();
Content.all().fetch();

Info.all().at(0).content(); // undefined.
```

anyone met this before ? how did you do that ?

Besides, [supermodel.js](http://pathable.github.io/supermodel/)
promises that

> Association properties are retrieved using a getter function. This
>   allows optimizations such as lazy-loading through collections. Other
>   associations may be lazy-loaded in the future as well.

Does this mean I can loaded the `Content` model associated with `Info.all().at(0)` through

```
Info.all().at(0).content();
```

even if instances of Content model haven't been fetched yet ?(seems it doesn't work)

How to achieve this kinda `lazy-loaded` ?